# processDatamap_beforeStart Hook - get the actual UID in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3, hook

Im using the

> processDatamap_beforeStart(DataHandler $dataHandler)

Hook. 
In a function I want to use the actual Uid from the new created Module, but I only get something like NEW58106331753043.15119885. I know there is a function for other hooks like `substNEWwithIDs[$id]`but I dont have the `$id`
Is there a way to get the actual new created Uid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. This hook is before the database record is created, so it doesn't have an actual uid yet. You'll have to use the `processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations` hook, which is after the record is created in the database.